Question regarding caching functions on Next.js v14
I am a beginner on NextJS. I would really appreciate your input and knowledge regarding caching functions on NextJS.
I am trying to cache the results from some functions inside a lib folder using cache from react:
data.ts:
import dbConnect from "./dbConnect";
import Lesson from "@/models/Lesson";
import { cache } from "react";
export const getLessons = cache(async () => {
  try {
    console.log("Fetched lessons")
    await dbConnect();
    let response = await Lesson.find().sort({ name: 1 });
    // Convert ObjectIDs to strings
    response = response.map((lesson) =>
      lesson.toObject({ flattenObjectIds: true })
    );
    return (response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch lessons on DB: ", error);
    throw error;
  }
});

I wish to use the results in a server component called Homepage and pass it to a client component called LessonsDropDown:
"use server";
import { getLessons } from "@/lib/actions/data";
import { Lesson } from "@/utils/types/AIReviewerTypes";
import LessonsDropdown from "./LessonsDropdown";

const HomePage = async () => {
  //1. Fetching on the server the lessons:
  let fetchedLessons: Lesson[];
  try {
    fetchedLessons = await getLessons();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("There has been an error fetching the lessons: ", error);
    fetchedLessons = [];
  }
  
  return (
     //Some code before...
    <LessonsDropdown fetchedLessons={fetchedLessons}/>
    //Some code after...
  );
}

So it seems to be fetching the lessons pretty fine, but I notice that I always keep seeing the console.log on the getLessons function everytime I refresh the Homepage. From my understanding, this means that this function is not being cached because it is being executed again... Is there something I might be missing? The lessons I get will always be the same, they don't change at all per request.
I am testing this on my local pc right now, not on production.
I tried using cache from react and debugging by console.logging on the cached function.

Here the nextjs documentation on caching should help with this. link
